# Unable to install Ubuntu on motherboard GA-H97M-D3H

Tags: software-installation

As a new member of this Ubuntu forum, I say greetings to you all! I cannot consider myself much of an advanced Linux guy, but I do prefer it over Windows in my work desktop PC. Which is very sad for me to find out that Ubuntu won't install or even run from live USB. Here's a few screenshots of my PC spec and BIOS settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What I've tried:

1. Creating bootable USB from mac with `unetbootin`, which makes the USB bootable only through UEFI. GRUB shows up upon booting, but choosing `install Ubuntu` or `try live session` ends up with blank screen.
2. Creating bootable USB from Windows with `rufus`, the USB is now bootable through Legacy. Upon booting, an Ubuntu/Gnome splashscreen shows up about 2-3 seconds, then an empty terminal about another 3 seconds before going blank again.
3. Tried with fast boot on and off. Same results.
4. Tried with secure boot on and off. Same results.
5. Tried with 4GB and 8GB flashdisk. Same results.
6. Tried Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 and 16.10. Same results.

At this point, I ran out of solution to make it work. I notice the official [Gigabyte product page](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4971#sp) implying that Linux won't work with my motherboard, but I have had successes installing on my other PCs with similar warning. As of now, I have to live with Windows, which I hope will not be for long as I am optimistic about the prospect that Linux users like you guys will always make things work.

Thank you and good day to you all.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thank you for that information, I will go on and check the link you provide now. And for the record, no I am not interested in dual-boot. Once Ubuntu is up and running I have no reason to have Windows on my PC.